# Trying to reprint from Cups

Tags: printing, cups

Trying to reprint a job from localhost cups - can anyone help???

Samsung_SCX_3400_Series-105     Unknown     Withheld    851k    1   completed at
Mon Feb 16 12:15:44 2015

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

`lp -H restart -i Samsung_SCX_3400_Series-105`

Where (from `man lp`):

- `-H restart` - restart a completed job
- `-i JOBID` - the job id

Mind that this will restart the job on the printer it was originally printed.

Comment: lp -H restart -i Samsung_SCX_3400_Series-105

Comment: do I just type the above command in terminal?

Comment: @Liz yes just copy and run it

Comment: now it's : lp -i ID_NUMBER -H restart